# Django Choice Form add selected options

Tags: django, selected

Hi all its my code if i choice in select list django work but i want after submit choices not be change.
After submit first choices again seeing.

My Form

```
class PostSorguForm(forms.Form):
    HIKAYE_CHOICES=(('1','En Son Çıkanlar'),('2','En Çok Okunanlar'))
    sorgu_form = forms.ChoiceField(choices=HIKAYE_CHOICES,required=False)
```

My view

```
class ArticleListView(FormMixin,ListView):
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'includes/article/article-list.html'
    paginate_by = 15
    form_class= PostSorguForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        if self.request.GET.get("sorgu_form"):
            selection = self.request.GET.get("sorgu_form")
            if selection == "2":
                queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-hit_count_generic__hits')
            else:
                queryset=Article.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('created_date').reverse()
        return queryset
```

my template

```
 <form method="GET" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" name="sorgu_form" id="id_sorgu_form" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            {% for x,y in form.fields.sorgu_form.choices %}
            <option value="{{x}}">{{y}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
          </select>
          </div>
      </form>
```

i want after query option selected

Answer (score 0):

i search a hours and i found now it's work
if you have another idea please write

```
<option value="{{x}}" {% if '?sorgu_form=2' in request.get_full_path  %}selected{% endif %}>{{y}}</option>
```